# Get number of pages in Oberver Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, product-collection

I have an Observer and I must get the number of pages (I need to know if there is > 1 page) in it. I tried on both collection and pager but no success :

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $layoutFactory,
    LayerResolver $layerResolver,
)
{
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
    $this->catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
}

public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
$this->catalogLayer->getProductCollection()->getLastPageNumber()
}
```

By trying this it gave me the result "1" but this is not the good one.

Any idea on how I should do it?

Comment: please attach your code

Comment: I updated my code!